Is SFML transform for vertex arrays not actually applied to vertices?
I'm trying to implement SAT collision detection in a game i'm making with SFML but I noticed that the vertices positions from the vertex array I used to make the player are not changing position even though the transform I applied to it works properly.
this is the Player class:
Player.h
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
    private:
    sf::VertexArray square;
    sf::Vector2f velocity;
    float speed = 10.f;
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Transform m_transform;

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

    public:
        Player() = default;
        Player(int screen_width, int screen_height);
        void create(int screen_width, int screen_height);
        void move(bool w, bool a, bool s, bool d);
        void setVertexColor(sf::Color color, int vertex);
        int getVertexCount();
        sf::Vector2f getVertexPos(int n);
};

#endif

Player.cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Player.h"
#include <cmath>
#include<iostream>


Player::Player( int screen_width, int screen_height)
{
    create(screen_width, screen_height);
}

void Player::create( int screen_width, int screen_height)
{
   float size = 60.f;

   square.setPrimitiveType(sf::Triangles);
   square.resize(6);
    
   square[0].position = sf::Vector2f(0.f, 0.f); //top left
   square[1].position = sf::Vector2f(0.f, size); //bottom left
   square[2].position = sf::Vector2f(size, 0.f); //top right
   square[3].position = sf::Vector2f(0.f, size); //bottom left
   square[4].position = sf::Vector2f(size, 0.f); //top right
   square[5].position = sf::Vector2f(size, size); // bottom left
   
   
   square[0].color = sf::Color(200,200,200);
   square[1].color = sf::Color::White;
   square[2].color = sf::Color(100,100,100);
   square[3].color = sf::Color::White;
   square[4].color = sf::Color(100,100,100);
   square[5].color = sf::Color(200,200,200);
   m_transform = getTransform();
}

void Player::move(bool w, bool a, bool s, bool d)
{
    float mod_velocity;
    sf::Vector2f t;
    sf::Vector2f pos;

    velocity = sf::Vector2f(0.f, 0.f);

    if (w)
    {
        velocity.y -= 1;
    }
    if (a)
    {
        velocity.x -= 1;
    }
    if (s)
    {
        velocity.y += 1;
    }
    if (d)
    {
        velocity.x += 1;
    }
    
    if ((velocity.x != 0.f) || (velocity.y != 0.f))
    {
        mod_velocity = sqrt((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
        t = velocity/mod_velocity;
        velocity = t * speed;
        
    }

    m_transform.translate(velocity);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    std::cout << "square[" << i << "].position:  " << square[i].position.x <<" " <<square[i].position.y <<std::endl; 
        
    }
    
}

void Player::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    states.transform *= m_transform;

    // draw the vertex array
    target.draw(square, states);
}

int Player::getVertexCount()
{
    return square.getVertexCount();
}

sf::Vector2f Player::getVertexPos(int n)
{
    sf::Vertex vertex = square[n];
    return getTransform().transformPoint( vertex.position );

}

void Player::setVertexColor(sf::Color color, int vertex)
{
    square[vertex].color = color;
}


Inside the class there is a cout that shows the positions of the vertices and they remain constant even when I move the player (and it moves on the screen). how do I get the actual position of the vertices?

please add "Player.h" content to the question

Sure... Pasting... Done!

In the Player::create method you assign a copy of sf::Transformable to class member m_transformable. And then you modify this copy instead of changing the original object. However, Player::getVertexPos returns original transformation, not modified.
To solve this problem you can either change return statement in the method to
return m_transformable.transformPoint(vertex.position);

... or apply transformations to original sf::Transformable base of your class (otherwise you don't need this base class at all).

Oh I see. I will edit the code to use the original Transform and answer with the revised code. Thank you very much (just point it out, the first solution you suggested also worked)
